# My VS code status bar is showing "42 files to analyze" numbers that keeps increasing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, statusbar, lag

[image]

It's showing that.

Sometimes it disappears and reappears after some time and I don't know why.

I tried to look into the extensions to see if it would explain, but I'm not sure.
I deleted and reinstalled VS code but it is still appearing.

I deactivated the telemetry stuff.

Comment: AFAIK this is just VS code telling you that it's parsing your code in the background to provide its features. As long as it still analyzes not all feature might be fully working (such as auto-completion not working or missing options). It should usually go away pretty quickly (especially when it shows such low numbers). Is this causing you any issues or do you just not want to see it?

Comment: thx, but Its slowing me down sometimes

Answer (score 1):

Same observation here, apart from the fact it is "31 files to analyze" in my case. Interestingly, though, it occurs in two independent workspaces with the exact same number of files (31).

Comment: Update:  After updating to today's version v2023.4.0 of the Python Extension the problem seems to be solved.